# Yii get many many bridge table get all columns

Tags: php, activerecord, yii

I have this tables:

```
Careeer { id(pk) , name}
Student { email (pk), ...}
Career_Student { student_email(pk)(fk), career_id (pk)(fk), semester }
```

In my Yii model I have this relation

```
'careers' => array(self::MANY_MANY, 'Career', 'Career_Student(student_email, career_id)')
```

and finally I have this query

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$params = array (':email' => $_SESSION['USER']);
$criteria->addCondition("email=:email");
$criteria->params = $params;
$result = Student::model()->find($criteria);
$careers=$result->careers;
```

My problem is that Yii doesn't retrieve "semester" column in my $careers variable.

¿How can I do that?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can express a `MANY_MANY` relation as a combination of two `HAS_MANY` relations that are connected with the [`through`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr#relational-query-with-through) option:

```
'career_student' => array(self::HAS_MANY,'Carrer_Student','student_email'),
'careers' => array(self::HAS_MANY,'Career', 'career_id','through'=>'career_student'),
```

Also make sure, that you define a relation for `career` in your `Career_Student` model:

```
'career' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Career', 'career_id'),
```

Now when you query for students `with('careers')`, both relations will be populated:

```
$criteria->with = 'carreers';
$result = Student::model()->findAll($criteria);
foreach($student->career_student as $careerStudent) {
    // You have access to the bridge table ...
    echo $careerStudent->semester;

    // ... and the connected career table
    echo $careerStudent->career->name;
}
```